# How to use importlib.resources.path(package, resource)?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I'm creating a _GeneratorContextManager with the following code.

```
try:
    import importlib.resources as pkg_resources
except ImportError:
    # Try backported to PY<37 `importlib_resources`.
    import importlib_resources as pkg_resources
from . import file_resources

package_path= pkg_resources.path(file_resources, "IWNLP.Lemmatizer_20181001.json")
```

Here is the debugger view of the variable package_path.

[image: debugger view of variable package_path]

Now I want to pass the path of the file "IWNLP.Lemmatizer_20181001.json" to another function:

```
 lemmatizer = IWNLPWrapper(lemmatizer_path=package_path)
```

The documentation says "The context manager provides a pathlib.Path object". How can I access the pathlib.Path object?

Comment: What is file_resources here?

Comment: file_resources is a python package containing the file IWNLP.Lemmatizer_20181001.json. Here is an example project: https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/importlib_resources_test .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
with pkg_resources.path(file_resources, "IWNLP.Lemmatizer_20181001.json") as p:
    package_path = p
```

p is a variable of type PosixPath and contains the full path to the file IWNLP.Lemmatizer_20181001.json. See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path .

Comment: `module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'path'`

Answer (score 4):

The `importlib.resources` `path` package has now gone in favour of the new `files()` API. To get the path as a string you now do this:

```py
from importlib.resources import files
package_path = str(files("file_resources").joinpath("IWNLP.Lemmatizer_20181001.json"))
```

There's no need to import your `file_resources` package. You can just pass it as a string name.

Note that `str()` only works on the return value of `joinpath()`. You can't use it directly on the instance of `Traversable` returned by `files()`.