# Get Path to Subpackage in Python

Tags: python-3.7, working-directory, pathlib, python-importlib

I have a project that needs updating from python2 to python3. It currently uses `pkg_resources`, which has significant overhead ([PyCon 2018 - Get Your Resources Faster with importlib.resources, by Barry Warsaw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsGFU2qh73E)). It will be packaged into a zip file. The relevant portions of the package structure are:

```
+-- project/
|__+ __init__.py
|__+ main.py
|__resources/
|  |__+ images/
|  |  |__ # program images
|  |__+ logging/
|     |__+ custom_logger.py
|__log/
   |__+ project_log.log
```

## Intent for Original Question

The intent for the original question was to ask "how does one get the absolute path to a subpackage from within another subpackage", but I did a poor job wording this. I thought since `current working directory` meant "path to where the `cwd` command is run from" that this could be used, but I later learned my understanding was incomplete. `current working directory` means (in layman's terms) "path to where the `cwd` command is run from **on the commandline**"). This is why I was having trouble. If I run my program from within the top-level package

```
C:\Users\usr\Destop\program>py main.py
```

and use `pathlib.Path.cwd()` in a `.py` file in any other subpackage (`resources`, `logging`, `log`), I will get the same answer:

```
C:\Users\usr\Destop\program
```

I learned this is proper behavior, but it means I cannot use relative paths to get from one subpackage to another (I need to use relative paths since I don't know where the end user will install this program on his/her machine).

## Relevant 2nd Part to Question that was Not Well-Clarified

Since part of my need is to update to python3, both `pkgutil` and `importlib.resources` were investigated. Each of these require resources to be treated as packages, so to update to use either of them, I have to add `__init__.py` to the folders `resources`, `logging`, and `log`. Not a big deal thankfully as this isn't a large program.

Note, for backwards compatibility with minimal code reediting, a namespace renaming has been recommended and used by others (e.g. see ([How to use importlib.resources.path(package, resource)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58520128/how-to-use-importlib-resources-pathpackage-resource)).:

```
try:
    import importlib.resources as pkg_resources
except ImportError:
    # Try backported to PY<37 `importlib_resources`.
    import importlib_resources as pkg_resources
```

Neither `pgkutil` nor `importlib.resources` has a method that directly returns "this subpackage" (in the way that `pathlib.Path.cwd()` "directly returns" the `cwd` without any extra code), but I think `importlib.resources` has a method I can use that will require the least amount of code and still be understandable to readers. Please note the ask is to get the absolute path to "this subpackage" and nothing else. I do not want to have to use a different approach.

The methods I would use is

```
try:
    import importlib.resources as pkg_resources
except ImportError:
    # Try backported to PY<37 `importlib_resources`.
    import importlib_resources as pkg_resources

with pkg_resources.path("logging", "__init__.py") as fl:
    path = fl.parent.resolve()
```

## Conclusion

Beyond this, I have no questions, because it will probably be judged as an "opinion" question. Please note the `__file__` method is unacceptable as this does not work with zip packages (see [PyCon 2018 - Get Your Resources Faster with importlib.resources, by Barry Warsaw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsGFU2qh73E)). If there is anything incorrect in this approach or if it can be improved, I would like to know.

Comment: Do you want the answer to be 'project' in both the cases? I think that might require knowing how deeply nested the directory structure is.

Comment: @mk03 I'm confused by what you mean. Are you talking about what `Path.cwd()` returns?

Comment: I wanted to ask what is your desired output?

Comment: Desired output would be absolute path to file. I might need to change to `cwd = str(fl.parent.resolve())` for this.

Comment: I think that would work

Comment: _CWD_ stands for current working directory, and usually (always?), yes it is the directory the user is currently browsing. That would explain the output of `Path.cwd()`. And what you are looking for is not the CWD, but something else.

Comment: @sinoroc Correct. This was not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package)

Comment: No, @wim does not answer my question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I changed my vote. -- Something I would like to add, not sure if it's actually relevant, I haven't really tested it, but anyway... In case the project is _zipped_, then I believe you can't really have a path to a (sub)package from this project, only to a file. If I am not mistaken, functions such as `importlib.resources.path(...)` hide this from the user, in that they unzip the file in a temporary file (directory?), and thus the _path_ is only valid for the duration of the context manager and only for that file. Probably the rest of the package is not unzipped at all.

Comment: @sinoroc Thank you and very true. The path will be to the temp folder where items are unzipped. This will work if the goal is to do "pathlib.Path path dividing" in a for loop, but not if the goal is to get the actual path. If we need the actual path, we should use the `__file__` method as @Bobby_Ocean has kindly presented. Alternatively, `pkgutil` has a walk directory structure method (`pkgutil.walk_packages`) whereas `importlib.resources` does not. `importlib.resources` has the `contents` method, but it does not recurse into subdirectories. Very interesting point...

Answer (score -2):

Any python file can access it's own location with **file**. Hence for example you could simply do

```
pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
```

to access the directory of the file that runs that code. This is independent from where you run the program from and/or where you install the program.

Comment: This does not work for code contained in zip files. (Can happen when `.egg`s are created or packaging for upload to PyPI)

Comment: Weird reason to downvote. I don't recall zip files being mentioned by the OP. Additoanlly, acnt you just set the zip flag to not safe in setup.py?

Comment: True, you can set `zip_safe` to `False`. Sorry for down voting. Only did so as answer could be improved since this does not work in all cases.

Comment: Right, but again, that wasn't even apart of the OPs question.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stackoverflow doesn't give me the option to upvote your answer unless you edit the question. If you add a comment about `zip_safe` to your answer as your edit, then I can upvote. Will that help? Zip safety is implied as part of the question. It asks for the correct way to get the `cwd` within a package structure in Python 3. Current best practice indicates accomodating for zip safety. No mention of this was given in your answer, hence it was downvoted as your answer was lacking and could be improved. However, i will upvote it back to 0 if you can edit your answer.

Comment: Oh, I don't really care that much about the vote point. Just thought that was odd. I have worked on many packages where we set zip_safe to false all the time. In particular, I am not even sure the exact bug you are referring to. There are many built in attributes to python files, like file, all, etc. I would think the standard answer should involve those. If there is a special case that causes an error, then that is when a specialized package should be recommended. Also, I thought that __file__ was used by packages like importlib, inspect, etc.

Comment: Also, we should point out that the OP does not mention a setup.py file nor pypi, nor installing their package. They only mention running it locally and want to know the simplest way to obtain the location of the file.

Comment: I'm the OP. I do not want the simplest way. I state I want the _best_ way. Your way is not the best way as I've clearly stated because it does not cover all cases. Hence, it is appropriate that your answer is downvoted.

Comment: No, `__file__` is not to be used by `importlib`. This is considered bad practice. Please see Barry Warsaw's PyCon 2018 video "Get your resources faster, with importlib.resources" <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsGFU2qh73E>.